# NSTextField becomeFirstResponder not work in awakeFromNib

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I want to set focus when form load but it didn't work in awakeFromNib.

```
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: have you tried it in a delegate method which is called later like `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code, and check that myTextField isn't nil? Right now you have insufficient code while reporting a generic problem.

Answer (score 25):

Just to quote the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/becomeFirstResponder):

```
Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.
```

Do this instead:

```
[[myTextField window] makeFirstResponder:myTextField];
```

Comment: Then check if myTextField is nil by NSLogging it like this before you make it your first responder `NSLog(@"%@", myTextField);

Comment: Works. Seems to work in either viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear controller methods. @user1628083 should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Swift version to this question:

```
textField.window?.makeFirstResponder(textField)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
- (BOOL) becomeFirstResponder
 {
 if (someCondition)
 {
     return NO;
 }

 BOOL retVal = [super becomeFirstResponder];

 // do your stuff
 return retVal;
}
```