# Lag When Activating Text Field Inside iOS 8 Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, ios8

I want to add a search field inside my custom keyboard that allows the user to search for content which can then  be input into the main text document for which the keyboard is being displayed.

However, calling `-becomeFirstResponder` on the `UITextField` object causes a 3-4 second lag during which no input is accepted. The same thing happens if I call `-resignFirstResponder`. I can set the `text` property of the text field just fine, but that means that there is no caret, and the text is truncated to fit.

On calling `(become|resign)FirstResponder`, I get the following messages in the log:

> 2014-10-28 13:39:50.920 Giffy KB[2073:514844] Received 0 images
>
> 2014-10-28 13:39:57.942 Giffy KB[2073:514745] <_UIRemoteInputViewController: 0x14762a030> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.theappical.giffage.giffagekb
>
> 2014-10-28 13:39:58.446 Giffy KB[2073:514745] View service did not balance fencing 'begin' messages with 'end' messages within a second; timing out.```

Other third party keyboards seem not to use textfields (they use custom views instead). Does that mean this is a bug at Apple's end, or is there something I can do to resolve it?

Comment: Check this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12460283/2522457.
also check below link https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6552509

Comment: @ShreyanshShah the first question is for OS X, the second one is basic user stuff, nothing related to code.

Comment: Still an active bug in iOS 8.1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filed a bug report with Apple for the same, ended up faking a text field using a UILabel. As of now (iOS 8.1 latest), this issue has yet to be resolved.