# NSSearchField occasionally causing an NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

The exception is "NSWindow: -_oldFirstResponderBeforeBecoming is not a valid message outside of a responder's implementation of -becomeFirstResponder." However, according to the stack trace the message *is* called from `becomeFirstResponder`, so I don't know what I am doing wrong. This is an intermittent error.

The user presses a key command sequence, which fires a menu item, which sends a message to the key window controller, which tells a search field on the window to become first responder.

Here's a summarised stack trace::

```
[NSException raise:format:]
[NSWindow _oldFirstResponderBeforeBecoming]
[NSSearchField becomeFirstResponder]
[MyWindowController focusSearchField]
[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:]
[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:]
```

The implementation of the window controller's action is very simple:

```
public var searchField: NSSearchField?
@IBAction public func focusSearchField(sender: AnyObject) {
    searchField?.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Try a dispatch_async with the becomeFirstResponder.  Let the event loop complete the turn it's on when the key press occurs.

Comment: Cheers I have tried that. It'll take a while to see if it works because it's a very intermittent problem. You should post your comment as an answer so it can be upvoted/accepted.

Comment: I might if it works!  [Similar sort of issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773827/how-can-i-determine-if-apple-methods-are-asynchronous).  I used async to let apple's code finish before doing what I need done subsequently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455650/nstextfield-becomefirstresponder-not-work-in-awakefromnib).

Instead of using `becomeFirstResponder`, you should use `NSWindow`'s `makeFirstResponder` method.

```
public var searchField: NSSearchField?
@IBAction public func focusSearchField(sender: AnyObject) {
    searchField?.window?.makeFirstResponder(searchField!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a NSPopover with a textfield inside. When I was removing it i was not setting the contentViewController to nil and it was not deallocating. When I was trying to open another popover the exception happened, I understand that it is because the first responder was resigned from a view that was not in a window